# How to connect Ios15 device to macos Catalina after a failed software update

Tags: macos, ios, catalina, data-synchronization

Last night i tried to connect my Iphone 13 pro(running iOS 15.0.0), to my macbook pro running MacOS Catalina(10.15.7). Realized I needed to do a update in order to connect the 2 devices. When the update was at 99% i had a network error and the update failed. I rebooted the macbook in hopes to have the update there to download once again in the update center, but lo and behold it was nowhere to be found.

At this time, ive tried almost everything Apple support suggested to no succes.

Is there a question to manually download this software update in MacOS, or to force the system to redownload it?

Comment: In the Terminal try `softwareupdate -l -a --include-config-data` and see if `Device Support Update` shows up. Also, `softwareupdate --his -a` to see if it has been installed. Finally, check `/Library/Updates`.

Comment: this is the output i get from the first command ` ❯ softwareupdate -l -a --include-config-data
Software Update Tool

Finding available software
Software Update found the following new or updated software:
* Label: XProtectPlistConfigData_10_15-2151
 Title: XProtectPlistConfigData, Version: 2151, Size: 949K, Recommended: YES,
* Label: MRTConfigData_10_15-1.84
 Title: MRTConfigData, Version: 1.84, Size: 4779K, Recommended: YES, `